# PUT/POST request throttle Rack attack redirect not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rackattack

So I have a form that makes XHR to external api on to get token and then submit to url which calls our db at "/update" on our backend. We are trying to limit number of requests a person can make using the form by using a rack attack throttle. So that when a limit is reached for example after two attempts the third should give a 429 error and then redirect to our page `/429`. I have this so far:

```
throttle '/update', {
    limit: 2,
    period: 60
  } do |req|
    next nil unless req.path == '/update' && req.put?

    req.ip
  end
```

Then for our throttle response we are doing:

```
Rack::Attack.throttled_response = lambda do |env|
headers = {
        'Location' => '/429'
      }
      [302, headers]
  end
```

The code does work and returns a 429 but the redirect doesn't happen even though we have `Location` in the headers. Also we have an endpoint where we do a `GET` and the same response redirects the user to `/429` successfully.

So how to redirect the user when making a `put` or `post` request with Rack Attack ruby on rails library? Is there another way to redirect the user? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the HTTP response status code. If you want the browser to redirect you need to use one of the 3XX status.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Rack
  class Attack
    throttle('test', limit: 1, period: 60.seconds) do |req|
      true
    end
  end

  # response
  Rack::Attack.throttled_response = lambda do |env|
    headers = {
        'Location' => '/test_redirect'
    }
    [301, headers, []]
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually had 302 when i was trying, it still doesnt work. I tried 301 too but nope.

Comment: I updated the code in the answer with the full module code (something basic). It works in my app. Give it a try